# Как правильно сравнить 2 числа неизвестного типа?

Tags: c

Пишу функции сортировки чисел. Хочу попробовать сделать их типонезависимыми. Для этого передаю внутрь ф-ию сравнения, которая будет отрабатывать внутри:
**прототип ф-ии сортировки:**

```c
void bubble_sort(void *array, int count, size_t size, int(*comparer)(void*, void*, size_t));
```

*(Размер массива передаю как `int` что бы, при отрицательном значении, сортировать по убыванию)*

Ф-ии сравнения разделил на 3 категории:

1. Целые со знаком
2. целые без знака
3. дробные

**Ф-ии сравнения:**

```c
inline int icompare(void* a, void* b, size_t size) {
    assert(size <= sizeof(int64_t));
    int64_t _a, _b;
    memcpy(&_a, a, size);
    memcpy(&_b, b, size);
    return _a < _b ? -1 : (_a > _b ? 1 : 0);
}
inline int ucompare(void* a, void* b, size_t size) {
    assert(size <= sizeof(uint64_t));
    uint64_t _a, _b;
    memcpy(&_a, a, size);
    memcpy(&_b, b, size);
    return _a < _b ? -1 : (_a > _b ? 1 : 0);
}
inline static int lfcompare(long double a, long double b) {
    return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
}
inline int fcompare(void* a, void* b, size_t size) {
    assert(size <= sizeof(long double));
    if (size == sizeof(float))
        return lfcompare((long double)*(float*)a, (long double)*(float*)b);
    if (size == sizeof(double))
        return lfcompare((long double)*(double*)a, (long double)*(double*)b);
    if (size == sizeof(long double))
        return lfcompare(*(long double*)a, *(long double*)b);
    return 0;
}
```

Если целые без знака и дробные отрабатывают нормально, то целые со знаком работают не правильно. По ощущению всё летит из-за неправильного копирования знака и структуры числа. Помогите найти решение или предложите альтернативный вариант написания ф-ий сравнения. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, понимаете, например для `int` и `unsigned int` я вам тотчас же напишу пример, который должен давать разные результаты *при одних и тех же входных данных*. Так что как вы намереваетесь сделать это *без использования типа*? - не понимаю...

Comment: Ответ будет такой: нужно так или иначе свести всё к однозначно известным типам. А ещё, например, `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(long) == sizeof(double)`. Какие типы в приоритете будут?

Comment: Если *очень надо* (и переносимость не важна и невыровненные числа не используются (вообще-то 90% программ попадает в эти условия)), то можно использовать пару младших бит указателя для передачи типа... (или вместо size можно передать данные о типах (или можно вместе))

Comment: @αλεχολυτ , В приоритете все стандартные типы. Вероятно надо как то разделять знаковые, беззнаковые и с плавающей точкой.
Может, в зависимости от одного из 3х этих множеств, копировать значение и каститить до самого большого (`char` или `int` до `long long`, а `float` до `long double` и тд) а тип передавать параметром. Хотя это всего предположение.

Comment: Вы лучше опишите для чего это вообще понадобилось. Есть ощущение [XY проблемы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/176217).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ , Я пытаюсь написать типонезависимые алгоритмы сортировки, тип которых известен только на момент отработки кода. На вход алгоритм должен принимать указатель на массив, размер массива и как-то определять тип. Ну и в любой сортировке так или иначе есть сравнение двух чисел. Со свапом значений я справился, а вот касаемо сравнения возникли сложности. Можно конечно ограничится натуральными числами или написать свой контейнер, но пули из колена вытаскивать интереснее)

Comment: Т.е. тип всё же где-то задаётся, явно или неявно. Значит его можно прокинуть и в функцию сравнения. А существенную информацию из ваших комментариев хорошо бы добавить непосредственно в тело вопроса через ссылку [edit].

Comment: Если пробрасывать тип в функцию сортировки, получим в ней switch выполняющий сравнения в зависимости от типа. Чем это лучше разных функций для разных типов?

Comment: В типонезависимых алгоритмах сортировки компаратор предоставляется пользователем. см https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort

Comment: @αλεχολυτ , изменения внесены в структуру вопроса.

Comment: @YoungSideways, ваш вопрос никак не связан с сортировкой. По-сути, вы пытаетесь отличить один кусок байтов от другого. Это невозможно сделать, пока у двух разных типов будет одна и та же неотличимая комбинация битов. Либо пока в компаратор не передается какая-либо метаинформация, позволяющая отличить один тип от другого. Как вариант можно обернуть примитивные типы в структуру, где будет поле `type`, которое будет хранить тип и `union`, которое будет хранить значение.

Comment: Другим вариантом будет оборачивание всех значений в большое число, первые биты которого будут служебными и указывать на тип, а остальные — представлять само значение. А компаратор уже будет с помощью побитовой магии эту информацию извлекать. Вряд ли есть переносимый способ сделать это, учитывая что верхняя граница размера стандартных целочисленных типов определяется реализацией.

Comment: @YoungSideways, вот [пример](https://pastebin.com/dUT3FRbS) с оборачиванием в структуру. Выглядит ужасно. Вариант с побитовой магией будет выглядеть не лучше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае, если известен только размер двух сравниваемых объектов арифметического типа, но не известен их тип, то наверняка определить значение какого из них больше невозможно.

И причина проста — одна и та же последовательность байтов может представлять одно значение, если её интерпретировать как объект типа `T1`, и в то же время представлять совершенно другое значение, если её интерпретировать как объект некоторого другого типа `T2`.

Например, предположим, что `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(unsigned long) == 4`. И есть такой код:

```
unsigned int ai = 1;
unsigned int bi = 16777216;

unsigned long al = 1;
unsigned long bl = 16777216;
```

Просматривая переменные `ai`, `bi`, `al`, `bl` побайтово и интерпретируя байты как имеющие тип `unsigned char`, мы могли бы обнаружить следующее соответствие:

```
ai -> 1 0 0 0
bi -> 0 0 0 1

al -> 0 0 0 1
bl -> 1 0 0 0
```

Т.е. в данном случае получаем, что `1 0 0 0  <  0 0 0 1`, если байты интерпретировать как объект типа `unsigned int`, но в то же время `1 0 0 0  >  0 0 0 1`, если байты интерпретировать как объект типа `unsigned long`.

---

Это был общий случай. На практике обычно выполняются следующие ограничения:

- Все целочисленные типы кроме `_Bool` не имеют битов заполнения (padding bits).
- Для представления знаковых целых используется [дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) (two’s complement).
- Знаковые целые не имеют trap representation.
- Для всех целочисленных типов используется одинаковый [порядок байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2): либо little-endian, либо big-endian.
- Если два вещественных типа с плавающей точкой (real floating types) имеют одинаковый размер в байтах, то они имеют одинаковое внутреннее представление.

После исправления небольших недочётов ваши функция сравнения будут работать на системах удовлетворяющих приведённым ограничениям, и в качестве порядка байтов использующих little-endian. (Кроме быть может типа `_Bool`. Сравнивать объекты данного типа приведёнными функциями не следует.)

---

В функции сравнения беззнаковых целых `ucompare()` необходимо инициализировать нулём переменные `_a` и `_b`.

```
uint64_t _a = 0, _b = 0;
```

Если `size < sizeof(uint64_t)`, то старшие байты переменных `_a` и `_b` оказываются неинициализированными. Чтение значения из таких переменных вызывает неопределённое поведение.

---

Аналогично в функции сравнения знаковых целых `icompare()` необходимо инициализировать переменные `_a` и `_b`. Если исходное число является положительным, то старший биты должны быть инициализирован нулём. Если исходное число является отрицательным, то старшие биты должны быть инициализированы единицами.

```
inline int icompare(void* a, void* b, size_t size) {
    assert(size <= sizeof(int64_t));
    int64_t _a = 0, _b = 0;
    if ( *((signed char*)a + (size - 1)) < 0 )
        _a = -1;
    if ( *((signed char*)b + (size - 1)) < 0 )
        _b = -1;
    memcpy(&_a, a, size);
    memcpy(&_b, b, size);
    return _a < _b ? -1 : (_a > _b ? 1 : 0);
}
```

---

Функция сравнения вещественных типов с плавающей точкой `fcompare()` потенциально может нарушать правила строгих псевдонимов ([strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650)), что ведёт к неопределённому поведению.

Например, если `sizeof(float) == sizeof(double)`, и функцию вызвать для сравнения двух объектов типа `double`, то будет выполнена ветвь

```
if (size == sizeof(float))
    return lfcompare((long double)*(float*)a, (long double)*(float*)b);
```

К объектам типа `double` обращаются как к имеющим тип `float`. Поведение программы не определено.

Лучше использовать функцию `memcpy()`:

```
inline int fcompare(void* a, void* b, size_t size) {
    assert(size <= sizeof(long double));
    if (size == sizeof(float)) {
        float _a, _b;
        memcpy(&_a, a, size);
        memcpy(&_b, b, size);
        return _a < _b ? -1 : (_a > _b ? 1 : 0);
    }
    if (size == sizeof(double)) {
        double _a, _b;
        memcpy(&_a, a, size);
        memcpy(&_b, b, size);
        return _a < _b ? -1 : (_a > _b ? 1 : 0);
    }
    if (size == sizeof(long double)) {
        long double _a, _b;
        memcpy(&_a, a, size);
        memcpy(&_b, b, size);
        return _a < _b ? -1 : (_a > _b ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Или `memcpy()` + union:

```
typedef union {
    unsigned char buff[sizeof(long double)];
    long double ld;
    double d;
    float f;
} float_union;

inline int fcompare2(void* a, void* b, size_t size) {
    assert(size <= sizeof(long double));
    float_union _a, _b;
    memcpy(&_a.buff, a, size);
    memcpy(&_b.buff, b, size);
    if (size == sizeof(float)) {
        return _a.f < _b.f ? -1 : (_a.f > _b.f ? 1 : 0);
    }
    if (size == sizeof(double)) {
        return _a.d < _b.d ? -1 : (_a.d > _b.d ? 1 : 0);
    }
    if (size == sizeof(long double)) {
        return _a.ld < _b.ld ? -1 : (_a.ld > _b.ld ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

И ещё, раз уж вы решили написать «универсальный компаратор», то при сравнении чисел с плавающей точкой следует помнить про [`NAN`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/NAN) — специальное значение, которое при сравнении операторами `==`, `>`, `<` с чем угодно, даже с самим собой, всегда возвращает `0`. Если сортируемый массив может содержать данное значение, то функцию сравнения необходимо переписать так, чтобы она явным образом задавала некоторый порядок `NAN` относительно других чисел с плавающей точкой, иначе результат сортировки может быть непредсказуем. Например, считать, что `NAN` больше положительной бесконечности.

Comment: По вам хоть книгу пиши. Спасибо за столь развёрнутый ответ с предоставлением дополнительной информации!